# Faint backdrop of another app always present in the phone

Tags: screen, oneplus

For some reason, I always have a backdrop of chess app on my phone. It isn't just chess but a few other buttons (back, toggle etc) from the OS a long time ago. This happened after I updated to a beta oneplus OS and since then It has never gone away. It persists through the updates and that backdrop is there even when the OS has not even loaded properly after the restart of the phone

Only a pic can describe the situation the best. However, when I took the screenshot the screenshot when viewed on my laptop does not have that backdrop

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description the chess app was active too long and has burnt-in into your OLED screen.

OLED pixels age faster the brighter they are lit and the longer they are on. An aged OLED pixel is getting darker and darker over the time so you see those ghost images.

Theoretically this can be fixed by reducing the brightness of those pixels that have not lost so much of their brightness or alternatively let those pixels also age so that they get to the same brightness as the more "worn-out" pixels.

On OLED TVs this is usually done automatically by the screen controller as it is otherwise very difficult to control the pixel brightness on a per-pixel level and also lit the correct sub-pixel.

For end users the only way to fix this is by replacing the screen.

Comment: I take that I should see somebody about this. Not the screen .. I mean.. the chess addiction

Comment: @NitinSiwach A chess game is a "bad enemy" for an OLED display: the changes are usually in a matter of multiple seconds or minutes so that images are shown a long time without any change. And even worse the chess board and the not moving meeple or empty fields don't change at all. For an OLED display it would be good if the whole board would be painted to a slightly randomized position. So at least every time you start the app (or every hour the complete board should move around on the display for a few pixels. I would suggest to add such an "OLED option" to the app author.

Comment: @Robert can this issue occur on an IPS LCD display too? A friend of mine had this issue on their Moto G4 Plus which had an IPS LCD display.

Comment: @Firelord To my knowledge LCD displays don't have anything that could cause a similar effect. The backlight is usually created by a few LEDs that are always lit together so any degeneration effects should affect all LEDs at the same time. Also an LCD panel doesn't care if the content changes or not.